# Doxygen'ing different instantiations of a templated function?

Tags: c++, templates, doxygen, instantiation

I have

```
template <typename T> foo<int, T>() { ... }
template <typename T> foo<T, double>() { ... }
```

And I want the `foo()` function doxygenated. What is the appropriate Doxygenation practice for such cases? Doxygenate both functions? The first? None? Use a common more general header and only document that one?

I'm asking this in the context of:

- What doxygen will put in the HTML file it generates (something I don't do for now, but I might in the future)
- What various IDEs look for and put in to pop-up descriptions.

Comment: Excuse me, but isn't this just opinion?

Comment: @Stefan Agreed, but I'm not 100% sure it's opinion-based enough to be off-topic.

Comment: @EricFinn: I personally agree with stefan here; documentation practices are very volatile.

Comment: One aspect that shouldn't be opinion is to ask yourself "What does a _naive_ user need?" - and do that.

Comment: @stefan: Tried to clarify why I feel this is not really a matter of opinion.

Comment: This still feels off-topic to me: "What will doxygen take?" -> just try. "What do IDEs do?" -> too broad.

Comment: @stefan: Ouch. Oh well. I guess I'll go experiment.

Comment: @einpoklum I didn't mean to come across as insulting. I'm truly sorry if it did.

Comment: It's not that I was insulted, it's just that you're telling me "Do some work to derive an answer to your question, rather than availing yourself of what people know." But it's fine, I'm not arguing.